# QuestDB mass CSV import - java process Out Of Memory

Tags: questdb

I'm doing a mass import of CSV files (200M+ records) into QuestDB running in docker via bash script (loop over list of files). Over time i can see the memory usage of java process gradually increasing to the point of OOM (16GB). Even after terminating the import script early, the memory usage of java process stay at the same level until i relaunch the container.

Bash import script:

```sh
for table in "${tickdb_tables[@]}"; do
  
  symbol=$(echo $table| cut -d'_' -f 1)

  curl  -i -F \
  schema='[{"name":"ts", "type": "TIMESTAMP", "pattern": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"},{"name":"symbol", "type": "SYMBOL"},{"name":"open","type":"FLOAT"},{"name":"high","type":"FLOAT"},{"name":"low","type":"FLOAT"},{"name":"close","type":"FLOAT"},{"name":"volume","type":"INT"},{"name":"timeframe","type":"SYMBOL"}]' \
   -F data=@$symbol.csv "http://localhost:9000/imp?name=CANDLES&timestamp=ts"

  rm $symbol.csv

  sleep 5
done
```

Table create statement:

```sql
create table CANDLES (ts TIMESTAMP, symbol SYMBOL, open FLOAT, high FLOAT, low FLOAT,
                      close FLOAT, volume INT, timeframe SYMBOL) 
timestamp(ts) partition by MONTH;
```

Is there anything i'm missing here, or is it some potential bug/memory leak in QuestDb? (didn't want to open issue until i'm sure i'm not doing something wrong)

Comment: It all looks valid, I'd suggest to open Github issue or go to QuestDB slack. From the glace it looks like QuestDB process cannot flush to disk fast enough and memory is held by OS / docker for too long, I'd need more details of the setup before trying to answer / suggest anything

Comment: Your script looks good, the issue is perhaps with lack of control over out-of-order parameters from REST API. I added an issue to track this problem: github.com/questdb/questdb/issues/1181

Comment: @VladIlyushchenko , AlexdesPelagos - thanks a lot, i'll keep an eye on the github issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is going on is that you partitioned by `MONTH` and one month data does not fit your RAM. When you ingest data Out Of Order which happens when you do symbol by symbol the ingestion process has to rewrite monthly partition every time you load new symbol file. Probably at some point partition does not fit RAM and QuestDB fails.

Try changing partitioning to by `DAY`. If possible split your csv files to day by day and load them in daily portions. Or create a table per symbol if you are not going to query them all together.